# How to compute the limit of $\lim_{n\to \infty} \int_{[0,1]} n\frac{\sin x}{x} e^{-nx} \sin(nx) dx$

Tags: real-analysis, integration

I tried to apply the Dominating Convergence Theorem but I can't find a function $g(x)$ such that $|f_n(x)| < g(x)$.
Can you give me some hint for this problem?

I tried to change the variable y = nx. So, I have

$\lim_{n \to \infty}\int_{[0,1]} n\frac{\sin x}{x} e^{-nx} \sin(nx) dx
=\lim_{n \to \infty}  \int_{[0,n]} \frac{\sin \frac{y}{n}}{\frac{y}{n}} e^{-y} \sin(y) dy 
= \lim_{n \to \infty}  {\int_{[0,\infty]} \frac{\sin \frac{y}{n}}{\frac{y}{n}} e^{-y} \sin(y) dy}
$

Do I allow to make the second equality?

Answer (score 0):

First make the change of variable $y=nx$. The integral becomes $\int_0^{n} \frac {\sin(y/n)} {y/n} e^{-y} \sin\, y \,dy$. Now the integrand is dominated by $e^{-y}$ which is integrable on $(0,\infty)$. Hence the limit is $\int_0^{\infty} e^{-y}\sin\, y\, dy$. You can evaluate this using  two  integrations by parts.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I did it. But after I changed the variable, I have: 

$\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{[0,1]} n\frac{\sin x}{x} e^{-nx} \sin(nx) dx
= \lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{[0,n]} \frac{\sin \frac{y}{n}}{\frac{y}{n}} e^{-y} \sin(y) dy$. I tried to put  
$\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{[0,n]} \frac{\sin \frac{y}{n}}{\frac{y}{n}} e^{-y} \sin(y) dy = \lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{[0,\infty]} \frac{\sin \frac{y}{n}}{\frac{y}{n}} e^{-y} \sin(y) dy$, but I don't know how to explain it.